# Is it correct to delete the subject from this sentence to avoid repetition?

Tags: formal-language, redundancy, conjunction-reduction

Is it correct to delete the subject from this sentence to avoid repetition?

- > I have OSHA and **I am** certified from the ministry as a ...
- > I have OSHA and a certified from the ministry as a ......

or I should simply say

- > I have OSHA and a certification from the ministry as as ...?

Comment: There are some likely typos in your choices; "and a certified" is probably supposed to be "and ***am*** certified", and "as as" is just wrong.

Comment: It is supposed to be "as a (complement of the sentence)" and ignore the (a) before certified.

Comment: Is it correct to say "I have OSHA and certified from the ministry as a (complement of the sentence) " without using the "am" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sort of context you can only delete elements which are identical in both clauses.

Your two clauses are

> I have OSHA
>   I am certified ...

You may therefore delete the second *I*, but must retain the verb *am*:

> I have OSHA and am certified ...

If your two clauses are

> I have OSHA
>   I have a certificate ...

you may delete the second *I have*:

> I have OSHA and a certificate ...

Note, however, that this is true only if the two *have*s are identical in sense and syntactical role. If your two clauses are

> I have OSHA
>   I have earned a certificate ...

the second *have* cannot be deleted, because in the first clause *have* is a lexical verb and in the second *have* is an auxiliary:

> I have OSHA and have earned a certificate ...